# unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSAUX

Tags: oracle, tablespace

My program creates a database schema. The queries related to tables and/or view creations work just fine but the first insert I do fails with

```
unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SYSAUX
```

error. It is a straightforward insert in a table that has just two columns, one two strings.

The user is obviously not set to use SYSAUX tablespace and has one on its own so:

- I don't understand where a SYSAUX-related failure can come from?
- How to fix this?

Comment: What is the user's default tablespace in `dba_users`, is the tablespace specified in the table creation statement, and what tablespace is it actually created against according to `dba_tables`? Are there indexes, explicitly or implicitly (from constraints), which have been created in `SYSAUX`? Look for anything in `dba_segments` for the owner and that tablespace, perhaps.

Comment: Maybe some object is created while the session was still connected to some System user. How did you separate the code that creates the non-system account, then how do you run the commands to create the objects ? Double check both Default and Temp tablespace for that new schema points to non-system tablespace.